# Eclipse J2EE Preview reads unfiltered resources from .metadata dir instead of m2e-wtp/web-resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e, m2e-wtp

I have a Maven WAR project, managed under Eclipse using `m2e` and `m2e-wtp`. In my `pom.xml`, I configure the `maven-war-plugin` to filter some resources in `src/main/resources`, and to put them in the classpath.

My files are correctly filtered, both in `project/target/finalname/WEB-INF/classes/` and in `project/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/WEB-INF/classes/`. However, when I run my webapp using `J2EE Preview`, the values are read unfiltered.

After investigating, I discovered that the files read, in my webapp launched on the `J2EE Preview` server, were located in `WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project/WEB-INF/classes/`, and that they were unfiltered.

So it seems that `m2e-wtp` is correctly doing his job here, but that the server adapter somehow messes up the filtering. It seems to acquire the unfiltered resources directly from `src/main/resources/`, to put them in the `.metadata/` dir, instead of acquiring them from `project/target/`.

How could I make sure that the server adapter acquires the filtered resources?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the filtering defined in the `maven-war-plugin` section is not correctly seen by `J2EE preview`, I needed to add a `resource` filtering section:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>myfile</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>  
</resources>
```

In that case, the file is correctly filtered in the directory `WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/project/WEB-INF/classes/`, used by `J2EE Preview`